# Use EmberScript in Ember-CLI app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, node-modules, broccolijs

How does one use emberscript in an Ember-cli app? I've installed the broccoli-ember-script node module but I can't figure out how to incorporate it into the default Ember-cli configuration of Brocfile.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var filterEmberScript = require('broccoli-ember-script');

var app = new EmberApp();
var tree = app.toTree();

tree = filterEmberScript(tree);

module.exports = tree;
```

Also, apparently ember-script will include Ember automatically so importing it will cause an error. There's [an open issue](https://github.com/ghempton/ember-script/issues/42) about this.